# Why don't x86-64 (or other architectures) implement division by 10?

Tags: x86, cpu-architecture, division, modulo

I'm familiar with compilers replacing division and modulo by a constant (e.g. `x/10`) with multiplication by a magic number `(x * 0xcccccccd) >> (32 + 3)`. [Compiler example here](https://gcc.godbolt.org/#compilers:!((compiler:g530,options:%27-xc+-std%3Dgnu99+-O3+-Wall+-Wextra+-fno-verbose-asm+-m32%27,source:%27%23include+%3Cstdint.h%3E%0A%0Auint64_t+div10_u64(uint64_t+x)+%7B+return+x/10%3B+%7D%0A%0Auint32_t+div10_u32(uint32_t+x)+%7B+return+x/10%3B+%7D%0A%27)),filterAsm:(commentOnly:!t,directives:!t,labels:!t),version:3).

```
        movl    $1717986919, %edx
        addl    $12, %esp
        movl    %ecx, %eax
        imull   %edx
        movl    %ecx, %eax
        sarl    $31, %eax
        sarl    $2, %edx
        subl    %eax, %edx
        leal    (%edx,%edx,4), %eax
        addl    %eax, %eax
        subl    %eax, %ecx
```

At the same time, I was a little bit surprised that there isn't some x86-64 instruction that does:

```
edx <= eax % 10
eax <= eax / 10
```

It seems like division by 10 is a fairly common operation for int-to-string or anything that requires decimal bases. x86-64 is also known for providing somewhat-niche instructions, many of which combine one or more common instructions (for instance, fused-multiply-add extensions.) It seems like the silicon could potentially do slightly better than the compiler?

I'm hoping to find an answer with some documentation or history behind it (not just speculation), if one exists. Though I understand it may be hard to find explanations for why architecture developers *haven't* done something.

Related:

- [Why does GCC use multiplication by a strange number in implementing integer division?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41183935/why-does-gcc-use-multiplication-by-a-strange-number-in-implementing-integer-divi)
- [Real mode supports BCD operations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33182491/why-bcd-instructions-were-removed-in-amd64)
- [Retrocomputing: Did any CPUs have a special instruction for multiplying or dividing by 10?](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/29591/did-any-cpus-have-a-special-instruction-for-multiplying-or-dividing-by-ten)

Comment: Most x86 extensions aim to be useful when they're new, which means only the latest CPUs have them.  And unfortunately most x86 software only does runtime CPU detection if at all, not a rebuild of the whole program for a specific CPU (like `gcc -march=native`), even in the open-source world where that's possible (a few Linux distros like Gentoo encourage this.)  A divide-by-10 instruction would be useful in lots of scattered places in a program, although maybe there are some parts of libc that do it enough to be worth making separate non-inline versions of int-to-string.

Comment: There's FBSTP etc. which I think you could use to obtain decimal digits from the BCD, but I don't know if it would have preferable performance to other methods.

Comment: Note that some highly-optimized int-to-string algorithms divide by larger powers of 10, e.g. divide by 100 and then only have to break up 0..99 into two decimal digits, increasing instruction-level parallelism.  (https://pvk.ca/Blog/2017/12/22/appnexus-common-framework-its-out-also-how-to-print-integers-faster/ / https://tia.mat.br/posts/2014/06/23/integer_to_string_conversion.html , and note that breaking up 2-digit numbers can use a faster multiply-based trick than what's needed for full-range: e.g. [Divide by 10 using bit shifts?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5558614))

Comment: @SimonGoater: FBSTP (https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/fbstp) is disastrously slow, like 200 to 280 clock cycles on recent Intel and AMD, although as fast as 130 cycles on Zen 2.  (https://agner.org/optimize/instruction_tables.pdf)  And microcoded as over 200 uops.  And has been getting even slower in more recent CPUs because nobody uses it so its performance barely matters. It *could* be implemented faster with a purpose-built execution unit, but it still has to take a `long double` input in an x87 register and round it to integer before starting, so there'd be a lot of overhead for `int` use

Comment: @PeterCordes I thought it would be slow, but if it can do 18 digits it might be useful in some cases, no?

Comment: @SimonGoater: Not with its current performance, even if all your numbers are full-size integers.  At 130 cycles on Zen 2, that's still 7 cycles per digit, not counting the overhead of unpacking BCD (2 digits per byte) to ASCII, and of getting integer data into it with store / `fild` in the first place.  And other modern CPUs are much slower, like 254 cycles on Ice Lake.  It was less slow on Pentium M / Core 2 (slow on Nehalem), and really old 32-bit CPUs would have slower 64-bit division

Comment: Pretty sure well-optimized itoa can go faster than that, maybe even naive itoa even with just 1 digit at a time mul/shr for a latency bottleneck of maybe 4 or 5 cycles per digit (with remainder calculation running in parallel with the next quotient.)

Comment: I suggest you research the history and ultimate demise of BCD for relevant information as to why x86 is the way it is with regard to converting binary to decimal. BCD exists mainly because of the diffiiculty of binary to decimal conversions. Integer division is hard and not even the latest AVX extensions support integer division or modulus operations.

Comment: Nowadays we'll use SIMD to speed up conversion. A dedicated division by 10 instruction would be terrible. [How to implement atoi using SIMD?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35127060/995714), [Parsing integers from string using SIMD](https://stackoverflow.com/q/78011357/995714), [Fast way to convert a string of 8 decimal digits into binary](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71570932/995714), [Can I use SIMD for speeding up string manipulation?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64975030/995714), [Parsing multiple ints from string at once using SSE/AVX](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74421322/995714),

Comment: https://lemire.me/blog/2022/05/25/parsing-json-faster-with-intel-avx-512/, https://github.com/simdjson/simdjson

Comment: @phuclv: Those are all about atoi, where the underlying problem is multiplication and addition.  itoa is the other direction, division and remainder.  For non-power-of-2 bases, each digit depends on *all* higher bits, no easy chopping up into groups to convert in parallel.  There would be some other use-cases like maybe decimal fixed-point, although for that you'd maybe want an immediate or register that gives a power of 10 to divide by.  Kernel code doesn't have to print a lot, but when it does it's not going to use SIMD.

Comment: @PeterCordes it's possible in the reverse direction as well: [64-bit Integers to Strings with AVX-512](https://sneller.ai/blog/avx512-itoa/), [Converting integers to decimal strings faster with AVX-512](https://lemire.me/blog/2022/03/28/converting-integers-to-decimal-strings-faster-with-avx-512/), [Converting integers to fixed-width strings faster with Neon SIMD on the Apple M1](https://dougallj.wordpress.com/2022/04/01/converting-integers-to-fixed-width-strings-faster-with-neon-simd-on-the-apple-m1/)

Comment: Because SIMD was already used for json I assume it must have the capability to do all possible kinds of json datatype conversions. I think you can also use [double dabble](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_dabble) to convert binary to string with SIMD

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ever since the mid 1990s and thus several years before work started on x86-64 it was generally known that integer division by a constant does not require an actual division operation, but can be computed via integer *multiplication*:

Torbjörn Granlund and Peter L. Montgomery, "Division by invariant integers using multiplication." *Proceedings of the ACM SIGPLAN 1994 conference on programming language design and implementation,* June 1994, pp. 61-72

There *are* applications that use integer-to-ASCII conversion a lot making it relevant to application performance. I seem to recall early web browsers were among these applications, as well as various software used in commercial processing. But such a conversion does not even need many division-by-constant operations either. One can convert the integer into a binary fixed-point representation once and then pull out the decimal digits one by one using multiplication with ten.

This technique of general base conversions is so old, I do not even have a reference for it. It was probably used manually prior to the advent of electronic computers. This is also how the `FBSTP` instruction in an x87 FPU works internally, or at least that is how I implemented it for the FPU of the Athlon processor. Now, `FBSTP` is rarely used, and microcode ROM is a very expensive resource, so I optimized the microcode for this for space rather than speed.

An implementation in ISO-C99 of this approach for the conversion of a 32-bit integer might look like the code below. The `umul32_wide()` function is a C-level equivalent of an x86 `MUL` instruction. To make this code run fast, one would want a fast integer multiplier. Providing fast *general* integer multiplication is important for performance in *many* contexts, and this was certainly known to the x86-64 design team.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string.h>

void umul32_wide (uint32_t a, uint32_t b, uint32_t *hi, uint32_t *lo)
{
    uint64_t prod = (uint64_t)a * b;
    *hi = (uint32_t)(prod >> 32);
    *lo = (uint32_t)prod;
}

void cvt_uint32 (uint32_t x, char *out)
{
    uint32_t hi, lo, num, digcnt;
    uint32_t dig;

    /* find first digit, in [0,4], separately */
    umul32_wide (x, 0x89705f41, &hi, &lo); // 2**61 / 10**9 rounded
    num = hi + (lo >> 31);
    dig = num >> 29;
    x = x - 1000000000 * dig;
    *out++ = dig | '0';

    /* convert number in [0, 999999999] to 4:28 fixed-point */
    umul32_wide (x, 0xabcc7712, &hi, &lo); // (2**28 / 10**8) * 2**30 rounded up
    num = (hi << 2) + (lo >> 30) + 1;

    /* pull out decimal digits one at a time */
    dig = (num >> 28) | '0';
    num = num & 0x0fffffff;
    digcnt = 8;
    do {
        *out++ = dig;
        num = num * 10;
        dig = (num >> 28) | '0';
        num = num & 0x0fffffff;
        digcnt--;
    } while (digcnt);
    *out = dig;
}

int main (void)
{
    char res [11] = {0};
    char ref [11] = {0};

    printf ("Testing uint32 exhaustively\n");
    unsigned int x;
    x = 0;
    do {
        cvt_uint32 (x, res);
        sprintf (ref, "%010u", x);
        if (memcmp (res, ref, 10) != 0) {
            printf ("error: t=%08u  res=%s  ref=%s\n", x, res, ref);
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
        x++;
    } while (x);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

One could ask: But what about the multiplication by ten in the loop? It is not needed. One could completely unroll the loop, replace it with a multiply-by-5 and dynamically adjust the fixed-point representation by one bit per step. A high-performance multiply-by-5 capability already existed prior to x86-64 in the form of the `LEA` instruction.

Another observation would be that the code shown above is of a serial nature, with limited ILP. That can easily be fixed by partitioning an integer into chunks (possibly recursively) using divisions-by-constant (10<sup>10</sup>, 10<sup>5</sup>) to create the chunks. Today even cleverer approaches are known as has been pointed out in comments.